# How to read the delay stored in the Datagram packet in the receiver using UDP

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, client-server, buffer

I'm using UDP to send a sequence code to my receiver, and I want to now measure the delay between when the packet is being sent and received. The only problem is I can't figure out how to read my delay from the packet after the sequence number.

Sender

```
    byte [] packetToSend = new byte[520];
    int seqNo = 0;

    while (seqNo < 100) {
        try {

            //Read in a audio data from the recorder
            byte[] buffer = recorder.getBlock();
            ByteBuffer header = ByteBuffer.allocate(524); 

            long sentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();


           header.put(buffer); 
           header.putInt(seqNo);
           header.putLong(sentMillis); 



            //Make a DatagramPacket from it, with client address and port 
            number
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacketheader.array(), 
             header.array().length, clientIP, PORT);

            //Send it
            sending_socket.send(packet);
```

Receiver:

```
         try {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[520];

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 0, 520);




            receiving_socket.receive(packet);
           // int seqNo = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getInt(512);
            long sentMillis = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getLong(508); 
            long receivedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long delay = receivedMillis - sentMillis; 
            System.out.println(delay);
```

So far I get numbers like 1498894798102, I'm guessing I'm reading from the wrong index in my ByteBuffer.wrap line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate a larger `ByteBuffer` and keep using the various `get()` (and `put()` when sending) methods. Lose all the `System.arraycopy()` calls.